# How to access to com.android.internal.R.bool in application ?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to access to get this parameter

`com.android.internal.R.bool.config_wifi_background_scan_support`  but it gives error like `com.android.internal.R` can't be resolved ?

I'm trying to use this way: `this.getResources().getSystem().getIdentifier("config_wifi_background_scan_support","id", "android")`

but i get nothing.

Anyone know how to get informations in `com.android.internal.R.bool` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have got it almost right.

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("config_wifi_background_scan_support","bool", "android");
```

gives you the correct id.